# Matching documents of mongodb with json

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way to verify that all documents of a mongodb are correctly entered i.e. to check that the data in JSON file and the inserted data are same?

If yes how to do it? Consider that there are 3 millions documents in db.

I want to do it with java script.

Thanks

Comment: Insert all documents, then read source files again and for each document, find its matching pair in the db and compare. Easy :)

Comment: Did you not test that you were writing data correctly before populating the DB with 3 million records? Sadly, you would need to iterate through all the records you want to compare in a script of some sort probably.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run a `find` for every document that you expect to be in the database, verifying that there is in fact an exact match present (just use the entire document as the match criteria).

In the future, you can use safe mode (safe=True in most drivers, but the syntax varies slightly) to make sure your writes do not fail.  Using safe mode will alert you as to the results of the write.